# Is it possible to use an object's attribute value to decide access?

Tags: spring-security

I am new to Spring Security. I have been working on creating a custom voter that will decide whether to grant permission or not based on the value of an attribute of the object. That is, if object instance A has attribute X with value i, user with ROLE_MGR has access. If object instance B has value j in the X attribute, then ROLE_MGR does not have access. is it possible to do that and if so, what do I need to do? if this is not possible we may decide not to use Spring Security.

Comment: yes it is, but what problems exactly are you having in implementing it ? This looks pretty straight forward.

Comment: I was using a custom voter (implements AccessDecisionVoter), but that does not have a way to acquire the domain Object. How can I check the attribute value of the domain object in a custom voter or do I need to look at another interface/class to customize?

Comment: I think you'll need to explain a bit more about "the object". Where is it and how do you work out which instance to access? That seems to essentially be where the answer lies. If it can't be accessed from the voter (by injecting a DAO, for example) then you'll need to explain why that is.

Comment: I used the term domain object because that's the term spring security uses for the objects that are secured using ACLs. I was hoping there was a way Spring Security provides to access the domain object directly so the custom voter can decide if a particular role has access to that particular object instance based on the value of a particular attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I need to use a custom permission evaluator. The snippets from my code are provided below for anyone that might be trying to do something similar:

security.xml

```
<security:global-method-security
    pre-post-annotations="enabled">
    <security:expression-handler ref="expressionHandler" />
</security:global-method-security>

<bean id="expressionHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
    <property name="permissionEvaluator">
        <bean id="permissionEvaluator"
            class="org.krams.tutorial.infrastructure.SomePermissionsEvaluator" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Service Interface
    @PostFilter("hasPermission(filterObject, 'READ')")
    public List getAll();

Custom Permissions Evaluator

```
@Override
public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authorities,
        Object targetDomainObject, Object permission) {

    boolean Decision = false;
    System.out.println("Initial Decision: " + Decision);

    Date cutoffDate = null;
    try {
        cutoffDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)
                .parse("January 1, 2012");
        System.out.println("Cutoff Date: " + cutoffDate.toString());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Domain Object Date: "
            + Post.class.cast(targetDomainObject).getDate());

    if (Post.class.cast(targetDomainObject).getDate().before(cutoffDate)) {
        Decision = false;
        System.out.println("In before");
    } else {
        Decision = true;
        System.out.println("In after");
    }
    System.out.println("Final Decision: " + Decision);
    System.out.println("--------");
    return Decision;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats possible, but first have a look at Spring Securitys domain object security. This is used to grant fine grained access on your objects, see here: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/domain-acls.html

Comment: I have already gone through the documentation for acl, and that does not specify how i can make a decision based on the value of the attribute of the domain object.

Comment: I agree, the OP wants to secure based on the value of a domain objects property, not the domain object itself.